# Ищу компоненты редактирования с подсветкой на питоне

Tags: python, gui, wxpython, pyqt

Гугление дало два основных результата: *styledTextControl* в *wxPython* и *QScintilla* в *PyQt*, оба - подвиды *Scintilla*.

В *tk* есть простой текстовый редактор, который, как я понимаю, не содержит понятия "лексер" и подсвечивает код только с помощью костылей.

Есть Pygments, но я не знаю, достаточно ли он быстр для подсветки в реальном времени.

Какие есть ещё альтернативы?

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал [pyqode](https://github.com/pyQode) для проекта [dev_window](https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window). Редактор совместим с `Qt` (`PySide`/`PyQt`).

Код для создания виджета-редактора можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window/blob/master/common.py) (функция `create_code_editor`).

Скриншот редактора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, интересный вариант, хотя пока только развивается и поддерживает всего три языка. Кстати, там Pygments. Как скорость?

Comment: Что-то с pygments было, когда писал setup.py. На больших текстах не тестировал, а так, сразу же при наборе подсвечивает